# How to pass the value of password field in to another class

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have a viewcontroller in which i have a alert view with text field. I am taking the user input here and i want this input to be available in my other view controller too.
So basically what we need to do is to pass this value to the other view controller. 
Please help me with this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Add a setter to the other view controller?

```
@implementation OtherViewController

-(void)setPassword:(NSString *)password {
  // Do something
}
```

Setters and getters are a generic programming concept that apply to all object-oriented language, not limited to objective-C.

The setter is responsible for taking a value in its input and "setting" that value inside the object in some way.  A getter simply returns whatever the value is currently set to.  You will have used these without knowing it.

Assuming you have the password in an NSString* variable called "password", then you just need to:

```
NSString *password;

// ... snip ...

[otherViewController setPassword:password];
```

I can't provide you with any more than this since I have no idea what your other view controller needs to do with the value.  Your other view controller will receive `-setPassword:` with the password you pass it, so it can do as it needs (e.g. perform a login operation at a remote server).

Comment: ok. Can you explain a little bit more.. i have never used getter and setter. Thanks for your qucik reply

Comment: i tried it and looks like its not passing the value and program breaks at [MembersViewController setPassword:pass]; MembersViewController is the class where i want this pass variable

Comment: You're going to have to post the code so I can picture what's going on better.  Does the program crash, fail to compile, or error in some other way?  You need to be more specific.  I assume you correctly defined `-setPassword:` ?

Comment: yes i did, and i think it's hindering the flow of the program may be i am using this at a wrong place.